# TYPO3 news extension

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I need to know how TYPO3 news extension is used as blog list with social share button? I used news extension.There is no section for blogs.Please specify a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The extension "news" has no separated content-element for blogs but the news-records by themselves can be used like a blog:

- Records can be sorted by creation-date but also by many other aspects
- The plugin to display the news in the Frontend exists in several variations, beside list- and detail-view there are blog-resembling views to display tags, categories and archives.
- About further features I advise the manual, it can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Index.html

Furthermore you still can verify and even influence the features with the options below:

- About features that are not mentioned in the manual like enabling comments for single posts you can search for further extensions that extend the news-extension, take care the provided page is mixed with results for tt_news which is not compatible. Also the compatibility related to the supported TYPO3 Versions might be an important consideration: https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=news
- For propositions and feature requests you can contact the author by creating issues on github: https://github.com/georgringer/news

Also consider that some own features might never need an own extension but only a tricky setup of the news-extension.

Finally you still could program an own extension to extend news or order someone to do it for you.